# How to access the environment name in Puppetfile

Tags: puppet

I'm using R10K with Puppet. The `Puppetfile` is basically DSL:

> Because the Puppetfile format is actually implemented using a Ruby DSL
>   any valid Ruby expression can be used.
>
> Ref: https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/puppetfile.mkd

So based on that, I can write some Ruby code in the `Puppetfile`. I tried and it does work. But what I don't find and know, is how to access some variables.

Ultimately, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
mod 'app',
  :git    => 'https://github.com/apps/app.git',
  :branch => ${environment}
```

Such that the module branch that is checked out is the same as the environment for which it is checked out. Obviouslt `${environment}` isn't the right syntax and isn't a real variable name.

So the best answer to this question would be how to get a variable of the environment and the second best answer would be how to reference a variable (and what variables are available) in the `Puppetfile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Of course, 10 minutes after I ask the question, I figured out the answer (been trying to solve this for hours)...*

In the `Puppetfile` you have access to the variables of the `DSL` class (see [DSL class in GitHub](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/8aec538385097c7c799fca770ea0c13fd092b869/lib/r10k/puppetfile.rb#L105). Thus you have access to `@librarian` which is an instance of the `Puppetfile` class (see [puppetfile.rb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/lib/r10k/puppetfile.rb)). And from there, you have access to its attributes.

So the answer to getting a branch of the name of the current environment is:

```
mod 'app',
  :git    => 'https://github.com/apps/app.git',
  :branch => @librarian.basedir.split('/').last
```

Not elegant and I wish the `puppetfile.rb` would give us a direct access to the environment but that works for me.

Comment: One question: Did you still use this? If I'm not mistaken, this doesn't work for branch names including a `/`, like `feature/foo`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @gf_ I still use it. Haven't upgraded Puppet to latest however. I don't know the solution to a branch with a slash particularly.

Comment: Since `r10k 2.4`, there is a feature called "Control Repo Branch Tracking". Have a [look](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/puppetfile.mkd#control-repo-branch-tracking).