# r10k: proper merging workflow with git

Tags: puppet, git, puppet-agent, r10k

I am currently running Puppet with in masterless mode. I am using [r10k](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k) for module and environment deployment.

Simplified version: The r10k control repository has two branches: *testing* and *production*. Changes in production will be automatically distributed to production servers. Changes in testing to some staging servers.

Now, if I am changing things in testing, I sometimes have to change the r10k control repository, too. A common example would be the `Puppetfile`, which currently looks like this in *production*:

```
forge 'forge.puppetlabs.com'

# Forge modules
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
mod 'puppetlabs/concat'
mod 'saz/ssh'

# Custom modules
mod 'ownmodule1',
        :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule1.git',
        :ref => 'production'
mod 'ownmodule2',
        :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule2.git',
        :ref => 'production'
```

The configuration for the Custom modules might look like this on the *testing* branch:

```
mod 'ownmodule1',
        :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule1.git',
        :ref => 'testing'
mod 'ownmodule2',
        :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule2.git',
        :ref => 'testing'
```

Now, a commit in *testing* might look like this:

```
+mod 'ownmodule3,
+        :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule3.git',
+        :ref => 'testing'
```

If I merge this to *production*, and are not careful, *ownmodule3* will be added to *production* with the *testing* branch, which could be fatal. This also prevents automated merging when all tests are successful.

How can I modify my repositories or workflow to prevent the accidental merging of branch specific changes?

Comment: Do you actually currently _merge_ your *testing* branch of r10k repository into *production*? What's your idea to do the automated merging? I am asking because it seems to me that it's not possible to automate it in your setup, at first glance at least.

Comment: No, no actually. But at some point merging from some branch to *production* is going to happen, and the commits might origin from *testing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since r10k 2.4.0](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/puppetfile.mkd#control-repo-branch-tracking), it is possible to have the puppet modules match the branch in the control repository. On the branch `testing`, the Puppetfile from my question might look like this:

```
mod 'ownmodule1',
  :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule1.git',
  :ref => :control_branch
```

This would result in the branch `testing` of the module *ownmodule* to be used in with *r10k deploy*. This is quite reliable. With `:default_branch` you can specify a fallback branch.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing hard-coded environment names used as refs in your `Puppetfile` with a variable substituted with current environment name would help make your Puppetfile mergable between branches.

**Pseudo** code:

```
mod 'ownmodule1',
  :git => 'https://git.example.org/configuration/ownmodule1.git',
  :ref => ${environment}
```

For **actual** code see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/661666/190032), but I don't guarantee that it will work in your setup, it's a bit hacky.

But of course to make your environments deploy properly after this change, you would have to create `production` branch in your modules along with `testing` and init them both with some minimal, no-op but compiling code for new modules.

PS If this answer is helpful and you decide to upvote it then please upvote the linked answer too.

Comment: I will try it and report back.

Comment: @M.Glatki Did you test this? If so: How are your experiences?

Comment: I have found that using the new *Control Repo Branch Tracking* feature is more reliable, and less prone to errors and regressions: https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/puppetfile.mkd#control-repo-branch-tracking